# Not a function when working in other places

Tags: php, jquery

To start here is the error I am getting. I am getting this by going into the console from Chrome.

```
OpenCAD.js:881 Uncaught TypeError: tag.play is not a function
at Object.success (OpenCAD.js:881)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at z (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

So what I am trying to do is add another button on my page to play another sound. There are already 2 buttons that do that and when I copy the code from the others it gives me that.
Here is code for the button.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="priorityTone('panic')" value="0" id="panic">Panic</button>
```

Here is the first part of the backend code which will do some stuff in the database to then run checks.

```
    else if (type == "recurring")
{
    var recurringButton = $('#recurringTone');
    var value = recurringButton.val();

    if (value == "0")
    {
        recurringButton.val("1");
        recurringButton.text("Priority Tone - ACTIVE");
        sendTone("recurring", "start");
    }
    else if (value == "1")
    {
        sendTone("recurring", "stop");
        recurringButton.val("0");
        recurringButton.text("Priority Tone");
    }
}
else if (type == "panic")
{
    var panic = $('#panic');
    var value = panic.val();

    if (value == "0")
    {
        panic.val("1");
        panic.text("Panic - ACTIVE");
        sendTone("panic", "start");
    }
    else if (value == "1")
    {
        sendTone("panic", "stop");
        panic.val("0");
        panic.text("Panic");
    }
}
```

That is the 2nd button and the new one I am trying to add which is where I copied it. It then goes into another part of the code where it changed a row in the database. It does that without anything going wrong.
Now it goes into the check part where it happens.

```
            if (data['priority'] == "ACTIVE")
        {
            var tag = $('#priorityToneAudio')[0];
            if (document.cookie.indexOf('priority=') == '-1'){
                document.cookie = "priority=played;";
                tag.play();

                $('#priorityTone').val('1');
                $('#priorityTone').text("10-3 Tone - ACTIVE");
            } else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
        else if (data['priority'] == "INACTIVE")
        {
            // Make sure the played cookie is unset
            document.cookie = "priority=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
            $('#priorityTone').val('0');
            $('#priorityTone').text("10-3 Tone");

        }

        if (data['panic'] == "ACTIVE")
        {
            var tag = $('#panic')[0];
            if (document.cookie.indexOf('priority=') == '-1'){
                document.cookie = "panic=played;";
                tag.play();

                $('#panic').val('1');
                $('#panic').text("10-3 Tone - ACTIVE");
            } else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
        else if (data['panic'] == "INACTIVE")
        {
            // Make sure the played cookie is unset
            document.cookie = "priority=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
            $('#panic').val('0');
            $('#panic').text("10-3 Tone");

        }
```

The if priority is the 2nd button again and panic is the new one I am wanting to add. It isn't all edited just to see if it works but all 3 use the tag.play but only the panic doesn't want to see it as it.
If anyone could help me get that to work that would be great.

Comment: are the `ids` unique? what is the output when you run `console.log(tag)` after the statement `var tag = $('#priorityToneAudio')[0];` and `var tag = $('#panic')[0];`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Not giving an output

Comment: what you mean by, **Not giving an output** is it is entering any of those checks then it surely must log something into the `console` hit `F12` or press `CTRL+SHIFT+i` to open the console, it gives an error, null, undefined or what?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I obviously know how to open the console since I gave an error from the console and it only gave the same error on panic but didn't log anything for the other.

Comment: I can give you the stuff and you can install it on your end.